# SCSS: Multiplying the output of a px-to-rem function causes "Undefined operation"

Tags: sass

I am trying to set up a reusable SCSS function that will allow me to specify basic measurements in pixels that I can use freely throughout the rest of my project. However I am unable to use the output of my function in math operations.

```css
@function to-rems($size) {
    $rem-size: calc($size / 16px) + rem;

    @return $rem-size;
}

$baseline-grid: to-rems(14px);

#box {
  width: $baseline-grid * 2;
}
```

The above method is how most online tutorials suggest making a pixel-to-rems converter. But when I try to use the output of this function in another operation, in the `#box` definition, I get this error: `SassError: Undefined operation "0.875rem * 2".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the expression `calc($size / 16px) + rem` produces a *string-typed output*, not a [number with a unit](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/numbers/). The simplest way to fix this is to multiply the calculated output by 1 with the unit which you need to convert into. The function will therefore return a number with the new unit.

```css
@function to-rems($size) {
    $rem-size: calc($size / 16px) * 1rem;

    @return $rem-size;
}

$baseline-grid: to-rems(14px);

#box {
  width: $baseline-grid * 2;
}
```

This produces the following CSS:

```css
#box {
  width: 1.75rem;
}
```